# Pattern to where this recursive formula converges?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

$$a_n=\frac {(x+a_{n-1})^2}{1+a_{n-1}}$$

$x = 0.1$ converges to $0.0125$

$x = 0.2$ converges to $ 0.0666…$

$x = 0.3$ converges to $0.225$

$x = 0.4 $ converges to $ 0.8$

For $0 < x < 1$, is there mathematically a trend or pattern to where $a_n$ converges for different values of $x$, and if yes, an equation that can predict that?

Background and motivation, why is this important, I'm working on a game theoretical system. A collusion attack vector scales with $a_n$

Comment: You have to prove that the recurrence converges, but assuming it does then the limit $a$ of $(a_n)$ is the solution to
$$a=\frac{(x+a)^2}{1+a},$$
which assuming $x\neq 1/2$ is $a=x^2/(1-2x)$.

Comment: Note that for $x>.5$ the only possible limit is negative, which (at least if we take $a_0>0$) is not possible, so the sequence can not converge in those cases.

Comment: @projectilemotion awesome. yeah that fits perfectly. it breaks at x>0.5 (becomes infinity) but that's been the case in my simulations for years so it fits. guess that means it converges when 0<x<0.5

Comment: @lulu thanks, yeah that's what my simulations have shown for years. thought I'd try and understand it mathematically so I can think better about it. big thanks!

Comment: @projectilemotion the reason why I was unable to solve this myself, is that I don't know how to take the limit of a recursive function. big thanks for helping me solve the issue.